# Evaluate integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}-1+x^2-\frac12x^4+\frac16x^6}{x^8}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

This is one of my final exam problems.

I notice the polynomial in the numerator are the first few terms of the Taylor Expansion of $e^{-x^2}$. But integral of each terms in the Taylor series of $e^{-x^2}$ is not convergent, and I fail to translate the fraction into some form of $e^{-x^2}$. My final attempt is to get the integral series $$\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{k!}{(k+4)!}\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}dx$$whose integral and summation cannot commute due to the divergence.

By Mathematica the solution is founded to be $\frac{8}{105}\sqrt{\pi}$ (which means the integral has some relation with $e^{-x^2}$). How to get it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Divide the integral into a sum of integrals. 
2) Evaluate each of them individually, using either the standard formula for integration of $x^{n}$ or the Gauss integral + integration by parts.

Edit: I also noticed that, evaluated in that way, the inegral is divergent at 0, so the limits (w.r.t. the variation of the lower integration limit) of the integrals at zero must cancel each other, which is where you use the coincidence of the first terms of the Taylor series with other summands

Comment: Also, where did you get the divergence from? Exponent is an entire function, $-x^2$ is entire, so $e^{-x^2}$ is entire and its Taylor series must converge everywhere

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku Yes, I forgot I can directly calculate the integral. The divergence of every term at 0 is ok because the whole function is convergent, hence I can ignore the terms gained with integral by part at $x=0$ and $x=\infty$. Later I will have a try. Thanks.

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku I mean each monomial's integral is divergent.

Comment: I think a $k$ is missing in the exponent of $x$

Comment: Final exam in what course?  (That may provide a hint of how to solve it.)

Comment: @GEdgar Mathematical Analysis(Calculus), no hints. May seem to be ridiculous, but the answer can just be gained with integral by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is inspired by @DaigakunoBaku, just some easy integral by part casting away the boundary terms, due to the summation of all the bouadary terms are zero, using $$\lim_{x \to 0}\int_{0}^x f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_x^\infty f(x) = 0$$ where $$f(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2}-1+x^2-\frac{1}{2}x^4+\frac{1}{6}x^6}{x^8}$$

So first we guess the answer is the final integration term of $\int e^{-x^2}/x^8dx$ ,denote $D = (1/N,N)$ and $B = \partial(1/N,N)$:

$$\begin{align}
&\int_D e^{-x^2}x^{-8}dx = -\frac{1}{7}e^{-x^2}x^{-7}|_B - \frac{1}{7}\int_D e^{-x^2}2x^{-6}dx \\
&=-\frac{1}{7}e^{-x^2}x^{-7}|_B+\frac{2}{7\times 5} e^{-x^2}x^{-5}|_B + \frac{2^2}{7\times 5}\int_D e^{-x^2}x^{-4} dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{7}e^{-x^2}x^{-7}|_B+\frac{2}{7\times 5} e^{-x^2}x^{-5}|_B - \frac{2^2}{7\times 5\times 3}e^{-x^2}x^{-3}|_B - \frac{2^3}{7\times 5\times 3}\int_De^{-x^2}x^{-2}dx\\
&= \frac{2^4}{7\times 5\times 3\times 1} \int_D e^{-x^2}dx\\
&+ -\frac{1}{7}e^{-x^2}x^{-7}|_B+\frac{2}{7\times 5} e^{-x^2}x^{-5}|_B - \frac{2^2}{7\times 5\times 3}e^{-x^2}x^{-3}|_B + \frac{2^3}{7\times 5\times 3}e^{-x^2}x^{-1}|_B \\
&\to \frac{8}{105}\sqrt{\pi} + \text{Boundary Terms}\\
\end{align}$$

Now here we check the summation of all infinite boundary terms is zero totally, by letting $\int_0^\infty = \lim_{N}\int_{1/N}^N$:

The summation of $x=N$ boundary terms are (combining the term gained with integral by part and the integral of polynomial)
$$
\begin{align}
&\{\frac{1}{7}x^{-7}-\frac{1}{5}x^{-5}+\frac{1}{6}x^{-3}-\frac{1}{6}x^{-1} \\
&+\frac{1}{7}e^{-x^2}x^{-7} - \frac{2}{7\times 5}e^{-x^2}x^{-5} + \frac{4}{7\times 5\times 3} e^{-x^2}x^{-3} - \frac{8}{7\times 5\times 3\times 1}e^{-x^2}x^{-1}\}|_{x=N} \\
&\to 0
\end{align}
$$

The summation of $x = 1/N$ boundary terms are
$$\begin{align}
    &\{\frac{1}{7}e^{-x^{2}}x^{-7}-\frac{1}{7}x^{-7} \\
    -&\frac{2}{35}e^{-x^2}x^{-5} +\frac{1}{5}x^{-5} \\
    +&\frac{4}{105}e^{-x^2}x^{-3} - \frac{1}{6}x^{-3} \\
    -&\frac{8}{105}e^{-x^2}x^{-1} + \frac{1}{6}x^{-1}\}|_{1/N} \\
    =&\{\frac{1}{7}(x^{-7}-x^{-5}+\frac{1}{2}x^{-3}-\frac{1}{6}x^{-1}) -\frac{1}{7}x^{-7} \\
-&\frac{2}{35}(x^{-5}-x^{-3}+\frac{1}{2}x^{-1})+\frac{1}{5}x^{-5} \\
+&\frac{4}{105}(x^{-3}-x^{-1})-\frac{1}{6}x^{-3} \\
-&\frac{8}{105}x^{-1} +\frac{1}{6}x^{-1} +O(x)\}|_{1/N}\\
\to& 0
\end{align}$$

Hence the estimation is finished. The calculation is more complicated than I thought, thanks @M.Wind. Is there a easier way?

Comment: This is not really a good answer to your own question. You just tell in words how the calculation can be done, and then present the final answer which you found using an online integrator. But that is not the same as actually solving your problem rigorously. If you had written this answer in your final exam, you would not have scored points.

Comment: @M.Wind Yeah you are right. The calculation of the boundary terms is not so trivial as I thought. I will present the detailed answer in minutes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @M.Wind The answer is uploaded.

Comment: You have improved your answer considerably. It is indeed a good procedure to perform integratation by parts, and then to expand the result in a Taylor series. This way you can demonstrate that cancellation of boundary terms indeed occurs. This was to be expected, given the nature of the integrand, but it still had to be demonstrated. Well done !

Answer (score 2):

For this type of question, I like to
employ [Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem). Indeed, your integral can be re-written as
$$\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+4)!} x^{2k},$$
which after the change of variables $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$, becomes

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty x^{-1/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k!}{(k+4)!} \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}.$$
Appealing to the Master Theorem, the integral reduces to
$$\frac{1}{2} \Gamma(1/2)\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(9/2)}=\frac{8}{105}\sqrt{\pi},$$
by Wolfram.

Comment: So quick and nice. Is this Theorem accepted as rigorous in mathematics?